# zsh: command not found laravel

Tags: php, laravel, zsh

I'm a newbie when it comes to Linux administration using bash... I was following a tutorial on how to install laravel 5.2 from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#installing-laravel)... installed it successfully...

firstly I installed composer and ran the following command

`composer global require "laravel/installer"`

after this put this in my path too in `~/.zshrc` like this

`export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

When I run the `laravel` command from the terminal I get the following error

```
➜  ~ laravel 
zsh: command not found: laravel
```

If I `echo $PATH` it shows it have added up in the path

Note: I have installed `oh my zsh` on my terminal...

What do I have to do to get it working please help

Comment: just do `composer create-project laravel/laravel ProjectName --prefer-dist`

Comment: Is there something called `laravel` in `~/.composer/vendor/bin`?

Comment: @miken32 yes there is a file called laravel in `~/.composer/vendor/bin` I've checked while i was trying to run the command

Comment: Then try running it directly: `~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel` and see if that works. If not, make sure it's executable.

Comment: M1 Mac - the below to my `.zshrc` done the trick for me. REMEMBER to `source ~/.zshrc` or quit and reopen your terminal for the setting to take effect.

`export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 261, accepted):

I think ZSH won't expand the `~` on `PATH`. Try this in your `.zshrc` file instead:

```bash
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Only works until I close out of the terminal. any ideas?

Comment: @PeterGMac. What do you mean? We are taking about the `.zshrc` file which is executed every time you start a new zsh session (i.e. every time you open a terminal). It only works until you close your terminal in the sense it works from when you open your terminal until you close your terminal?

Comment: why i have to add this every time i open the terminal?

Comment: This also solved a problem I had with migrations not working with  `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` when using homestead along with mamp pro socket (after setting up unix_socket, right localhost and everything else, also successfully tested connection, still couldn't run migrations) so THANK YOU!

Comment: In my case, I had to use different path:
`export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: For me also only `export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` works. I'm on ubuntu 19.04

Comment: @PeterGMac. You can add that code to `~/.zshrc`, restart terminal and it will work (I'm using Iterm2 with Zsh on Mac)

Answer (score 55):

Try to do this:

```bash
export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm on Manjaro using ZSH and oh-my-zsh

Comment: This is the right answer for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: this should be the right answer !

Comment: Thank god! after few hours of searching finally found the answer that works for me.

Comment: Working for PopOS linux with Laravel Installer 5.5

Answer (score 29):

As a follow up to Chris' answer,

The command `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` will **work**, but **only for your current terminal session**.

If you would like the path to always be available when zsh launches, add `PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` to the bottom of your `~/.zshrc` file. Run the `zsh` command or restart your terminal and `laravel` will be available in every session you start.

Comment: You need to run: source ~/.zshrc to make it available in the current session also (without restarting terminal).

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu 20.04 / 22.04 with zsh (Oh My ZSH!) and macOS.

Add Laravel cli with composer :

`composer global require laravel/installer`

edit : `~/.zshrc`

add to file :

```
export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

run:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: but macos has `~/.zprofile` File for this

Answer (score 10):

I got the same problem on macOS Sierra.
Edit your .zshrc file with

```
PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

My solution was:

```sh
echo "PATH=\"$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH\"" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

- Then type `laravel`

More info [here](https://vinnyfs89.gitbook.io/knowledge/technology/programming-languages/php/laravel#zsh-command-not-found-laravel/)

Answer (score 3):

> Make sure that you've [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56942162/4433536) and [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) installed on your
> system:

Open a new terminal shell, navigate to your project's directory and run the following command:

```bash
echo -n 'export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' << ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```

If it errors asking for permissions run this:

```bash
sudo !!
```

*This will run the previous command with `sudo` appended to it.*

*If your machines using*:
`laravel@version{5,6,7}.x`, *running*: `shell PHP >= 7.2.5`

```bash
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel demoblog
```

Alternatively, [these instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/master#your-first-laravel-project) may serve you well.

Answer (score 1):

When you run command `laravel` in your terminal, you call the laravel file inside composer/vendor/bin directory.

If none of the above works, then find where your vendor dir is by running:

`composer global about`

you will see something like:
"Changed current directory to /home/username/.config/composer".

That means that your vendor dir is located in that path.
Then add an alias in .zshrc file:

`alias laravel="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin/laravel"`.

Now you are pointing to the 'laravel' file in your filesys using the same command as you would normally.

or you can add composer to your path:
`export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`, which is the recomended way.

Answer (score 1):

Put this to .zshrc file:

`export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

And make sure you run:

`source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

macOS:

```
$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Windows:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

GNU / Linux Distributions:

```
$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin or $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

For Linux:

---

make sure you fully add the path to composer to your system path

```
export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

or better still edit the .zshrc file as below

```
echo "PATH=\"$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH\"" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

for MACOS

type on terminal

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

open `~/.zprofile`

add this :- `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Run:- `source ~/.zprofile`

Answer (score -1):

I too was getting the same error while creating a new Laravel project using composer but anything mentioned about the path didn't solved it and a simple trick help to resolve this issue.

Try to run this command on the terminal of your project folder :

`composer global require laravel/installer`

Article from laracasts helped me:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-command-not-found-by-zsh-on-macos