# Updating php version on mac

Tags: php, macos

I want to update php version, currently I have 5.5.38 and I want 7.1

What I tried so far is using this command:

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1
```

I tried several different versions but none of them worked.
It opens bash_profile for a second and then I get `Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM` and message below:

Buffer written to /Users/Morpheus/.bash_profile.save.6

Not sure what went wrong and why it won't update...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: when I googled I found this , https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/upgrade-php-mac-os-x/

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen I already checked that and uses the same or similar command to the above....

Comment: you probably didn't add it to your path. `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` paste the code in your terminal

Comment: You can try this https://magestar.in/change-php-version-for-bash/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Use Homebrew:

I would probably recommend installing [homebrew](https://brew.sh) to manage such installations for you. With that installed you can just run the following command to install php7.1

```
brew update
brew install php@71
```

Comment: Its not working , displaying error:Error: No available formula with the name "php" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps

Comment: In addition, if you want 7.3 then the command should be-
`brew install php@7.3`

Comment: Make a search by using `brew search php`. You will get all PHP related formulas that available in the brew. Now, you can install it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 90):

Install php

```
brew install php@7.2
```

Install the required PHP to your PATH

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then make sure it's all working

```
php -v
php --version
```

This command will show you where your ini file is loaded

```
php --ini
```

Comment: if you are using valet you will need to run valet install to update previous valet php configuration

Comment: also if you are using oh-my-zsh
update path in your .zshrc export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH" and restart terminal

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me on macOS Mojave version 10.14.6. Thank you.

Comment: For MacOS Mojave, this is the only solution that works. Great!

Answer (score 37):

The simplest way to update the version of php on Mac is via Homebrew.

If you do not have brew please visit https://brew.sh/
or install via command in terminal:

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

When finished installing Homebrew, run the following commands:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew unlink php@56  
brew install php@71
```

> You might get an error if PHP 5.6 has not been installed by brew previously, but don't worry, you can simply continue.

You can also change the version to 7.0 by replacing the command from above commands from `brew install php@71`  to `brew install php@70`.

You can check the output by command.

```
php -v
```

If the output of `php -v` still doesn’t echoes the version 7, simply type this command and hit enter in terminal.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: While I was able to upgrade and install via this method it still showed as php 7.1 until I did the last export PATH step, so kudos for that! Also I don't know if anything changed but I had to run the install script as `brew install php@7.3` with a dot between major/minor versions

Comment: brew install php@7.4

Answer (score 16):

The solutions above did not work for me on Big Sur I kept on getting:

```
WARNING: PHP is not recommended
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built: Dec 21 2020 21:33:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

To fix this I used the following steps:

#### Step 1 | Tap into another repository of formulae

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
```

#### Step 2 | Install the desired PHP version

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```

Other options are:

```
php@5.6
php@7.0
php@7.1
php@7.2
php@7.3
php@7.4
php@8.0 
php@8.1 or known as just PHP
```

#### Step 3 | Link the PHP Version

```
brew link --overwrite --force php@7.4
```

#### Step 4 | Restart Terminal

#### Step 5 | Check PHP version

```
php -v
```

You should now see the new version.

```
PHP 7.4.25 (cli) (built: Oct 21 2021 00:29:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.25, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

This also solved my issues with PHP syntax in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thanks!!! This is the unique way it worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

For me none of the mentioned worked. So to upgrade from `php@7.3.11` to `php@7.4` I had to install

```
brew update
brew install php@7.4
export PATH=/usr/local/php7.4/bin:$PATH
```

Then force overwrite as following:

```
brew link --overwrite --force php@7.4
```

then

```
php -v
```

output: `PHP 7.4.24`

Answer (score 5):

Try to use below command

```
brew update
brew install php@72
```

If it shows below error,

> "Error: No available formula with the name "php"

try

```
brew install php@7.2
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use below command

```
brew update 
brew upgrade php
```

or

```
brew reinstall php
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use the command, its working fine with me

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

Comment: this worked for me, and was made permanent after I updated my .profile with the line  `PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 3):

In case you guys run all install commands above but when checking the PHP version, it is still linking to the old version. So you guys may want to update the `PATH`.

In my case, I open the `.bash_profile` which located in `HOME` directory by command:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then, I add the path to the new version of PHP:

```
PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.4/bin:<other_paths>
```

Finally, run `source ~/.bash_profile` command to refresh the terminal window and checking the PHP version again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can `brew upgrade php7` 
or `brew uninstall` old php version.

Last, I recommend you `brew install php-version`, php-version can help you change your php version

Answer (score 0):

Im running Mac OS 10.13.8 and this worked all the way to PHP version 7.3

curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3.8-20190811-205217

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install php@x.y
```

`brew link --overwrite --force php@x.y`

For Mac remember this is the last step & don't forget to kill & restart the terminal

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.0/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```