# Updating PHP 5.6 to 7.0

Tags: php, laravel

I pulled an existing Laravel project from Git and created .env file which is missing. When I ran a composer install, error message

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- illuminate/support v5.6.27 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support v5.6.27 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support v5.6.27 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support v5.6.36 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support v5.6.5 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support v5.6.3 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.- illuminate/support v5.6.27 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support v5.6.28 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support v5.6.2 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support v5.6.27 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support v5.6.27 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support v5.6.27 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

After which I install PHP 7.0 version. I tried to check the change using command which PHP but it still indicate PHP 5.6.27.
I ran composer install which installed to some point but ended with the following suggestion and error

```
- Installing phpunit/phpunit (6.5.8): Downloading (100%)         
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection (For loading routes from a service)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/class-loader ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/filesystem ()
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib (Provides RandomLib for use with the RandomLibAdapter)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides the PECL libsodium extension for use with the SodiumRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-uuid (Provides the PECL UUID extension for use with the PeclUuidTimeGenerator and PeclUuidRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing moontoast/math (Provides support for converting UUID to 128-bit integer (in string form).)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-doctrine (Allows the use of           Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as Doctrine field type.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-console (A console application for generating UUIDs with ramsey/uuid)
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml ()
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server via PHP Driver)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing sentry/sentry (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
 league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver and SES mail driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (~2.5).)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-pcntl (Required to use all features of the queue worker.)
laravel/framework suggests installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (Required to use the Mailgun and Mandrill mail drivers and the ping methods on schedules (~6.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Required to use Flysystem caching (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Required to use the Flysystem Rackspace driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing nexmo/client (Required to use the Nexmo transport (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing predis/predis (Required to use the redis cache and queue drivers (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/dom-crawler (Required to use most of the crawler integration testing tools (~3.3).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to psr7 bridging features (~1.0).)
intervention/image suggests installing ext-imagick (to use Imagick based image processing.)
intervention/image suggests installing intervention/imagecache (Caching extension for the Intervention Image library)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pcntl (Enabling the PCNTL extension makes PsySH a lot happier :))
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation.     You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
filp/whoops suggests installing whoops/soap (Formats errors as SOAP responses)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.5.5)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (^1.1)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
```

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/folder/projectname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233
```

I have installed PHP 7.0, but the version is yet to change. PHP 7 is the required version. How do I switch? I'm using Laravel on mac

How do I solve this problem? I need to set generate the APP_Key and start the serve.

Comment: How did you install the new php? Used Homebrew?  running this command might be helpful `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` as suggested here: https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-upgrade-your-version-of-php-to-7-0-on-macos-sierra-e1bfdea55a63 or check https://php-osx.liip.ch/

Comment: Using Homebrew may save you some time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41872735/5704410

Comment: I ran this command 

curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0

Comment: can we see that line please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using brew?

```
$ brew unlink php56
$ brew install php70
```

Remember to restart apache...

Comment: He uses MacOS not ubuntu/debian.

Comment: So he can use brew:
brew unlink php56
brew install php70

Comment: i tried $brew unlink php56 but got this error   Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php@5.

Comment: @Kyslik ahh I see! Then you're justified ;) haha either way OS X should be avoided, but putting personal opinions aside, I will rm my comment

Answer (score 0):

After various attempts to solving this issue, the following are the steps that worked for me:

```
brew install brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

which shows "Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone." To solve this problem, I ran

```
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
```

then

```
brew install brew-php-switcher
```

The above command installed brew-php-switcher dependencies and also php version 7.2.6. Running

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

to insert export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.6/bin:$PATH

Checked my php version with "php -v"

PHP 7.2.6 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2018 10:09:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.6, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

P.S: I noticed that when I check the version using which the answer I got was

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

I dont know why that is but just in case you encounter this, try using php --version or php -v