# Mac: switch to php8.0 installed by brew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

After Mac OS full reinstall I perform php 8.0 install by `brew install php`.
Unfortunately, brew didn't make this version active: `php --version` report about 7.3 (not recommended version).
I cannot unlink this version because it's not installed by brew, so `brew link` also doesn't have much sense.
How to bring latest php to system level and completely forget about php7.3 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update PHP to 7.4 macOS Catalina with brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684713/update-php-to-7-4-macos-catalina-with-brew)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523183/how-to-use-the-php-that-brew-installed

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872645/updating-php-version-on-mac/56942162

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to tell your terminal where to find your new installed php.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/sbin:$PATH"
```

And you need to add it to the bash_profile if you want all terminals to keep using your installed version.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This is for terminal use only. So not for your web servers.
In the future, when you install other versions, you can update the profile with:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Just updated from php 7.4 to 8.1. Was asking myself why php7.4 was still running while typing php -v. Changed the path as mentioned above, and php 8.1 is working.