# php -v stuck at 7.1.33 and not switching to 8.0.9

Tags: php, macos, path, homebrew

## General

I am using macOS 10.13.6

So, what I want is to work with laravel 8, which requires php 8, and what I did was installing php@8.0 via homebrew:

```
$ brew update
$ brew tap shivammathur/php
$ brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0
```

PHP 8 was installed successfully and after that, I ran this command:

```
$ brew link --overwrite --force php@8.0
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9... 24 symlinks created.
```

After that I went to .bash_profile and exported **/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9/bin** and **/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9/sbin** to the *$PATH* sysvar, saved the changes and executed the command:

```
$ source .bash_profile restart
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2020 13:49:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

## What I did next

Then I decided to check StackOverflow to find some useful info that could help me out.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67224660/mac-switch-to-php8-0-installed-by-brew) it said:

> tell your terminal where to find your new installed php.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/sbin:$PATH"
```

Since **/usr/local/opt/php@8.0** is a pointer to **/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9/**, it must work as well (but it does not). Messing up with $PATH for some time has lead to nothing but a strong headache, so I decided to continue my search… [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523183/how-to-use-the-php-that-brew-installed) it said:

> You have to make your Apache use the PHP that you just downloaded.

I didn't know if I really needed that, but just in case I did, I added

```
LoadModule php8_module /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
```

to the apache httpd.conf file and ran:

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

Nothing happened. [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142504/switch-of-php-versions-not-working-on-mac) contained the list of instructions, which looked like this:

- brew install php@<desired_package>
- brew link --force php@<desired_package>
- brew services start php@<desired_package>
- export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@<desired_package>/bin:$PATH"
- export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@<desired_package>/sbin:$PATH"

That one did not work either. I'm stuck. I do not know what to do. Please, help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: These steps did work for php@7.4 actually. Seems one cannot upgrade to php 8 on a machine running macOS High Sierra…

Answer (score 0):

Add the `bin` directory in Homebrew's prefix to your path, then the linked PHP version should work.

```sh
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

Also, please upgrade your macOS. Homebrew does not support High Sierra now.

Comment: I'd love to upgrade to newer versions of macOS, but I have MacBook Pro early 2011

Comment: Added `bin` to `PATH` and that didn't solve the problem. Still running php@7.4

Comment: Try unlinking `php@7.4` and relinking `php@8.0` -> `brew unlink php@7.4 && brew unlink php@8.0 && brew link --force --overwrite php@8.0`

Also, make sure you did not add php@7.4 location to your PATH, remove that if that is in the PATH